# jQuery - is it possible to add params to the URL and load before page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to add params to page url as it starts to load?

i.e i have a URL:

> admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list

But i need to add to the URL

> ?sort_by=date&sort_order=desc

Comment: You'll need to be clearer. What do you mean by "As it starts to load"? From the previous page? You can edit the url using javascript, pretty much from the start of the `<head>` block...

Comment: Where do you want to put this code? On the page that hasn't start to load yet????? Besides if you change the url, then it'll reaload the page = redirect

Comment: Well i dont want to load the page, apply the params and load the page again... as would then be loading twice so thinking if can force the reload before full content is loaded so maybe appears to just be loaded once... maybe i should do this with ajax? its using cs-cart and maybe i can sort that way... let me check quickly

Comment: @James — If you want to do that, then do it server side.

Comment: yea been trying, but no available hooked to hook into the sorting function to set default sorting so trying to do with js some how lol

Comment: This might be possible, though I'm not sure I understand the situation completely. You could change the query string in <head/>, and it should affect scripts that load after that script loads. However, this requires that your page uses these variables in JavaScript. In other words, the page must sort in JavaScript or via AJAX. If the data is sorted on the server (if the server reads the params and sorts the data then sends the output to the browser), then it won't work--in this case, you would need to change the params and redirect or make another request to reload the page.

Comment: Yea im having a play with the ajax function at the moment within their docs... $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('?dispatch=cart.cart_list&sort_by=date&sort_order=desc'), {
   'full_render': true
  });

Comment: ok kind of worked it out using cart.post.php to add redirect to the controller but its giving me now This webpage has a redirect loop but going in right direction i think

Comment: You're barking up completely the wrong tree here (also known as an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/135956)). If you want to do this server-side, either: Internally, redirect to the appropriate URL or return an HTTP redirect to the desired URL. If you know what the URL should be at page load, then you should be loading that page... If you provided some information on the server-side technology, we might be able to help

Comment: Just saw your latest comment - yes, that's what you need to be doing, just make sure that you only redirect once. Eg the Url you redirect to has _something_ that indicates the redirection has been handled. Usually this is a case of checking the parameters you're sending anyway, but in some (rare) cases you can add a `redirect=` parameter to track what's happening

Comment: yea thats issue im facing as of course its just looping so trying to work that out... dont know php that well haha

Comment: seems i can use: fn_redirect("cart.cart_list&sort_by=date&sort_order=desc"); but of course its looping so looking to maybe check if url has params and if does not to redirect maybe?

Comment: done this, which so far seems to work  but might need to change if effects anything else within that controller but you have helped me, forcing mind in direction lol so thanks! if(empty($_GET['redirect'])) {
  fn_redirect("cart.cart_list&sort_by=date&sort_order=desc&redirect=true");
 }